# How does r fit the intercept in a glm with known coefficients?

Tags: r, glm, intercept

I have fitted a glm model with known coefficients as in [fit glm with known coefficients and unknown intercept](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31571299/fit-glm-with-known-coeffiecients-and-unknown-intercept), but my question is now what method R uses to do it.  Is R just using the maximum likelihood with only the intercept as unknown variable? And can anyone give me a formula and reference for this calculation?

Comment: this is closer to a statistical than a programming question.   I don't know whether you're liking for a statement of the maximum likelihood equation, or a reference to  iteratively reweighted least squares; have you looked at the references from `?glm` ?

Comment: I posted it here because it is an r-calculation. Sorry if I should have done differently. As I have understood r uses irls to fit the coefficients, but most formulas leaves out the intercept without loss of generality. Assuming I already know the coefficients for beta, I would like a formula or method for the alpha i.e. the intercept. Does the irls correpond to max.lik when the intercept is the only value to be fitted?

Comment: It's not silly to have posted here, I'm just not sure it's a programming question. An intercept-only model is still a perfectly reasonable GLM, so all the properties of GLM/IRLS are inherited.